# Why do I get this "Invalid handle!" error in Python cx_Oracle?

Tags: python, cx-oracle

This question is related to one of my earlier questions posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8646968/how-do-i-read-cx-oracle-lob-data-in-python).

I have this code:

```
dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn(hostname, port, sid)
orcl = cx_Oracle.connect(username + '/' + password + '@' + dsn)
curs = orcl.cursor()
sql = "select TEMPLATE from my_table where id ='6'"
curs.execute(sql)
rows = curs.fetchall()
print rows
template = rows[0][0]
orcl.close()
template.read()
```

When I do `print rows`, I get this:

```
[(<cx_Oracle.LOB object at 0x0000000001D49990>,)]
```

However, when I get to `template.read()`, I get this error:

```
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: Invalid handle!
```

Now when I swap `orcl.close()` and `template.read()` like so:

```
template.read()
orcl.close()
```

I don't get any error at all.

Additionally, this ONLY happens when the data type is LOB. If the data I'm retrieving is a string or integer or any other non-LOB data, `print rows` prints all my data and `template.read()` does not throw an error regardless of it being before or after the `orcl.close()`. My question is, why does this happen?

Comment: The docs on LOBs say that Oracle optimizes queries against them by returning only handles to the LOBs, not the LOB data itself.  My guess is `cx_Oracale` follows this convention and that the `cx_Oracle.LOB` object is just a proxy to the remote data.  Given that, closing the connection to the server will kill the proxy as well.

Comment: @sr2222 Ah, ok. That makes sense. Do you think you could point me to the docs that say this?

Comment: Was trying to find something straight from Oracle, but have this http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Oracle/DBA_tips/LOBs/LOBS_1.shtml